# how to get weather report from a picture in android

Tags: android, weather

When My app Starts it should on The Camera and when the user captures the picture my application should able to say the weather information with the help of that picture.i.e the picture taken by the user should be the source to get the weather details of particular area.Is it Possible if so? Can You Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If the device has a gps or can get coordinates from network and the camera embeds the coordinates into the image as [exif data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#Geolocation), you can read those coordinates and time the picture was taken and send the information to a weather service that has an api to retrieve the current weather for the location at that time.

However not all devices support these features and users can choose to disable the location information being a part of their pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bunch of weather APIs that you can talk to once you've got the GPS coordinates for the location that the photo was taken at: https://live.temboo.com/library/keyword/weather/